Unexpected measurements results with prototype transformer-type inductive conductivity sensor (TICS)
I previously created a post about my prototype conductivity sensor on the Electronics Stackexchange because I suspected a problem in my electronic design (more details can be found there):
Electronics Stackexchange post
However after some testing it could seem as if the problem might not be related to my electronic design, so I was wondering if the problem might be chemistry related.
My test consists of a beaker with 500 ml of reverse osmosis water to which I add table salt every 7-9 minutes while measuring the conductivity with a reference conductivity sensor and my own prototype sensor. The beaker is on a magnetic stirring base to mix in the salt and keep the liquid homogeneous. At lower conductivity levels everything seems fine but at higher conductivity levels my prototype sensor output starts decreasing over time. The water temperature remains fairly constant around 25°C and the reference conductivity sensor also seems to remain stable over time.
EDIT: My question is mainly about my prototype sensor output decreasing over time at higher salt concentrations and not really about the relationship between salt concentration versus electrical conductivity.
Some graphs (Ratio : ratio between driving signal and sensing signal, can also be perceived as sensor output because the driving signal is constant in this case):



This question is similar to: Decrease in molar conductivity with increase in concentration. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

What is the assumed dissipated power and the internal sensor temperature? Is possible that at higher conductivity, the sensor is warming itself up and its magnetic properties change?

@Mithoron I do not think it is the case of decreasing molar conductivity, but a case of comparing responses of the experimental and the reference conductivity probes. The relative response is not linear (would be even with decreasing molar conductivity if all worked right). And it is eventually time dependent, if I got this part right.

@Mithoron Thank you I did not really consider the relationship between conductivity and concentration and it not being linear. However, as mentioned in the other comment, my question is my prototype sensor output decreasing over time at 'higher' salt concentrations. As a sidenote, during this specific test the salt concentration ranges from 0 to 8 g/L or 0 to 0.14 M.

@Poutnik Good question, I have a temperature sensor about 1 mm from the toroids with the goal of measuring the water temperature, but if the toroids internal temperature would increase it should also be measured by that sensor. I just did a test where I let it measure for 30 minutes under heavy load (in free air, with a resistor instead of salt in water) and the sensor reported less than 1 degree difference with the ambient temperature, so I don't think there is a significant increase in the internal temperature.

@Poutnik Yes you are correct, I already measure the conductivity with a reference sensor, the relationship between salt concentration and conductivity is not really a concern for me, but rather the non-linear response of my sensor (while in theory it should be linear, according the what I have read) and the output decreasing over time.

And what if the nonlinearity is expected, if taking in account possible sources of nonlinearity in both magnetic behavior of the sensor and solution behavior in alternating magnetic field?

@Poutnik I found the issue, I was driving my toroid into saturation. I have posted about it in more detail in my post on the electronics stackexchange.

The problem did appear to be on the electronics side, I was driving my toroid into saturation. I posted the answer with more details on my post on the electronics stackexchange linked above.

It was my suspicion there may be something with magnetic nonlinearity and saturation is the perfect example.

Yes, this is chemistry related: conductivity is not a linear function of concentration.
An extreme case is the dependence of conductivity of sulfuric acid ($\ce{H2SO4}$) on concentration, as shown in this graph by Horace E. Darling in "Conductivity of sulfuric acid solutions" [Journal of Chemical & Engineering Data 9.3 (1964): 421-426.] from a previous question:

Up to ~20%, conductivity of $\ce{H2SO4}$ increases steadily with concentration, and then the slope decreases, until 30%, where conductivity decreases.
In addition, there might be issues with using magnetic induction to measure conductance for at least three reasons:

The mobility of ions changes with concentration, so there might be a frequency-dependent effect.
Due to lesser penetration at higher frequency, there is a "skin effect". This also is frequency dependent.
The shape and volume of the measurement chamber might also influence results, since they might affect signal penetration.

In short, I think your idea of magnetically measuring conductance is valid, avoiding contamination of the solution with metallic electrodes, but will require calibration for each chemical and test chamber.

The OP chart curvature is not caused by nonlinearity of conductivity as function of concentration, but by nonlinear experimental  probe response compared to reference probe response.

Thanks for your input, but indeed the relationship between electrical conductivity and salt concentration is not my concern, but rather the non-linear response of my sensor and its decreasing output over time at higher salt concentrations. I will edit my original post to try and clarify it more.
